# Android External Storage vs. SD Card

Tags: android, storage

After reading the Android documentation on storing files, I see that External Storage can include both a removable sd card AND storage that is internal to the device, i.e. not removable. Is there a way to distinguish between removable storage and non-removable storage when choosing to save a file to External Storage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616974/how-to-check-internal-and-external-storage-if-exist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087510/check-if-the-sdcard-is-present-boolean-is-always-true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can't reliably distinguish between internal and external (SD) storage.

At first glance it might seem like you can use something like `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` but this isn't reliable, because your "primary external" storage device might very well be the device's internal memory, not the SD card.

The doc for [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) states:

> *Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.*

As an example, my LG G4 has an external SD card installed, and I can see it with adb (`external_SD`):

```
$ adb shell ls -la /storage/
drwx------ root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 USBstorage1
drwx------ root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 USBstorage2
drwx------ root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 USBstorage3
drwx------ root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 USBstorage4
drwx------ root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 USBstorage5
drwx------ root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 USBstorage6
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 emulated
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2015-07-31 08:19 external_SD
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-02-28 01:10 sdcard0 -> /storage/emulated/legacy
```

However, the various APIs for external storage return values that prove that the device is using internal memory as its "primary external" storage:

- Environment.getExternalStorageState: *mounted*
- Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated: *true*
- Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable: *false*
- Context.getExternalCacheDir: /storage/*emulated*/0/Android/data/com.codeblast.storagetype/cache
- Context.getExternalFilesDir: /storage/*emulated*/0/Android/data/com.codeblast.storagetype/files

Running the code on an emulator without external SD card returns exactly the same results.

So you can't assume that `/mnt/sdcard` means a physical SD card.

You may have reconsider what you're actually trying accomplish rather than trying to detect the storage type. :-)