# How to find Sd card is availeable or not in android

Tags: android

I have no SDcard in my Device but the following code return me true.

```
   Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

Comment: check this out, maybe it will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087510/check-if-the-sdcard-is-present-boolean-is-always-true

Comment: `Boolean isSDPresent = ...`. Wrong variable nams. Better: `boolean externalMemPresent`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
boolean isSDCardmounted = false;
  isSDCardmounted  = Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
    if(isSDCardmounted ){
        //Sd card available
    }else{
       //SD Card not available
    }
```

Comment: same result.it returns true even my device has no sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Boolean isSDAvailable = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    if(isSDAvailable )
    {
      // yes SD-card is Available
    }
    else
    {
     // Not Find sd card
    }
```