# Detect removable sd card on android device with internal memory

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to detect if removable sd card mounted to android device. My device has internal memory  and when i am using this
`Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);`

It always return true because my device has internal memory. How can i detect removable sd card in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087510/check-if-the-sdcard-is-present-boolean-is-always-true