# How to find out existence of adopted sd card in android?

Tags: android, storage

I'm using ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs to get a list of storages in android.
It shows up my devices internal storage path and sdcard path.

In Android 6,
you can format the sd card as "internal", called adopted storage.
When checking ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs it only returns one single path.

How would I know if this single path given is a internal storage or internal storage+adopted sd card? Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Maybe this response can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12087556/4845438